# how can I make my buttons bigger

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I am trying to enlarge my buttons height. I am trying to inflate the row but it is not working any idea?

check out my updated code with a relative layout and tablelayot...

tried enlarging the row and the tablelayout same result...

I tried enl
XML

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/black_bg"
android:layout_centerVertical="true">    
 <TableLayout android:id="@+id/row1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="45dip"
   android:paddingRight="5px"
   android:paddingLeft="5px"
   android:paddingTop="15px"
   android:paddingBottom="5px"
    android:layout_weight="1">
<TableRow
   android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="50dip">
    <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/btn_service_plus"
      android:layout_marginRight="4px"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textSize="12dip"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:text="1"
      android:layout_weight="1" 
      />
<Button 
      android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
      android:layout_marginRight="4px"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:textSize="12dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      />

<Button 
      android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
      android:layout_marginRight="4px"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:textSize="12dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      />


<ToggleButton 
  android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:textStyle="bold" 
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:textSize="12dp"
      android:layout_weight="1" 
      android:background="@drawable/menu_button_layout"/>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Put atleast 1dp in button width.

Comment: @Deepak He is using `layout_weight` - `0dp` for the width is the only correct choice here. He also wants to modify the height, not the width.

Comment: Have you tried increasing height of the row? what exactly is "not working"?

Comment: tried increasing height of the row(see above) but the buttons are staying the same height ...

Comment: you are trying to enlarge your button height right? post the full layout file as i tested your code and its  working fine.

Comment: its taking height of the TableRow's parent

Comment: tried enlarging the height  of the table same result..

Comment: check my answer i edited your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited your code now check this

```
 <RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/black_bg"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true">    
 <TableLayout android:id="@+id/row1"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100dip"
 android:paddingRight="5px"
android:paddingLeft="5px"
android:paddingTop="15px"
android:paddingBottom="5px"
>
<TableRow
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="50dip">
<ToggleButton android:id="@+id/btn_service_plus"
  android:layout_marginRight="4px"
  android:textColor="@android:color/white"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:textSize="12dip"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:text="1"
  android:layout_weight="1" 
  />
 <Button 
  android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
  android:layout_marginRight="4px"
  android:textColor="@android:color/white"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:textSize="12dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  />

 <Button 
  android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
  android:layout_marginRight="4px"
  android:textColor="@android:color/white"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:textSize="12dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  />


 <ToggleButton 
  android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
  android:textColor="@android:color/white"
  android:textStyle="bold" 
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:textSize="12dp"
  android:layout_weight="1" 
  android:background="@drawable/menu_button_layout"/>
 </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 7):

I might be a bit late to the party, but I think CJBS (see comment on Akram) is right. Unfortunately I cannot make a comment so I will post this as an answer (which should be good too because I give an answer).

Since the answer of the OP is already answered, I'll provide an answer that will help the people with the same question:

This will make the button text larger:

```
android:textSize=""
```

This will make the button-height larger:

```
android:height=""
```

This will make the button-width larger:

```
android:width=""
```

EDIT:

Using 'min' before 'width' or 'height' might also be a good idea.

Example:

```
android:minWidth=""
```